# No response from bot after publishing to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I've built a bot locally on my PC, using the `Microsoft Bot Builder v3.15.2.2` NuGet package.

Using the `bot emulator v3.5.3.6` on my PC, I can connect to the bot and interact with it. After I published the bot to our Azure envirnoment, and using the `Test in Web Chat` option in the `Bot Service` page for my bot, I notice that the bot is not responding. I enter a message, press enter, but nothing comes back from the bot.

I have registered the bot using the `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/` website, and I copied the app ID and password from that site into the app settings of my bot web.config file. I can verify that those settings appear correct in the `Application settings` tab for my Azure Web App for the bot.

I've spent a long time looking at log streams, and diagnostic files via Kudu, but it's not clear to me why there is no response coming back from the bot. As another test, I edited the `default.htm` file of the project to include an `iframe` to host the bot chat window (the iframe code was obtained via the `Channels` tab on the bot service page). When I typed into the iframe, the same result occurs - I do not get a response from the bot.

Remote debugging with Visual Studio isn't really an option, as our company has strict security in place, and I doubt they will be willing to open ports for me to attach Visual Studio to the Azure Web App.

I'm at a standstill here, since I do not know what to do look for in diagnosing the issue. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

EDIT

I opened the DevTools and attempted to chat with the bot using the `Test in Web Chat tab in Azure. The following error was caught in the console window:

```
botchat.js:20 WebSocket connection to 'wss://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/<FOO>/stream?watermark=-&t=<FOO>' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Note that I replaced token values with `<Foo>` for privacy. I hope this might be useful clue for someone.

Comment: Did you append /api/messages to your endpoint?

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going there - in this case, I'm not interacting with the bot via the emulator, or by using the uril with `/messages/api`. I'm using the `Test in Web Chat` tab that appears in Azure Portal for the bot service page for the bot. The web chat automatically connects to the bot for me, I do not need to give a url.

Comment: If you developed your app with .NET SDK, then when you register your bot in the portal you are suppose to give the endpoint as https://.../api/messages

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. Yes I passed the full url including `/messages/api/` when I registered the bot in Azure. I've double checked the `Overview` tab for my bot, and the Messaging endpoint` contains the full url with `/messages/api`.

Comment: How was this bot created?  It is not generally required to create anything at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/  The Bot Service templates will do this for you automatically.

Comment: Hi @JasonEvans, If possible, you can try to create a new Web App Bot, and publish your bot application to that corresponding Azure App service, then check if new bot service can work as expected.

Comment: You can also try to connect to the bot hosting on Azure using bot emulator, and check if some useful info are logged in emulator LOG window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to do with our network proxy.

Basically, since testing the bot in Azure Portal uses websockets, our proxy by default blocks websocket access. So, boom, no response from the bot.

By changing our network settings for the bot config, we are no receiving responses from the bot.

Comment: Thanks Jason, could you please explain more about websockets and how to change the network settings for bot config.

Comment: @VinodkumarG Thanks for commenting. I'm really sorry, but since this was a year ago, I no longer have that project available to me. Thus I do not remember what the config changes were. I feel really silly for not mentioning what specific changes were made in my answer. Apologies. Maybe this could help? https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1057

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your messaging endpoint is set to `https://{botname}.azurewebsites.net/api/messages` in the bot settings.

Comment: I've just double checked to make sure; it is indeed set to `https://{mybotname}.azurewebsites.net/api/messages`

Comment: Try republishing it with the option "Remove additional files at destination" checked. I've had problems with the default project before.